# List interface not working on my servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am currently working on a login page where I'll be needing to check if the user's input is valid by comparing every item in an ArrayList with the input.

Here is how I implemented it in my servlet

```
public class UserLogin extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        String un = request.getParameter("username");
        String pw = request.getParameter("password");

        UserInitializer user = new UserInitializer();
        user.initializeSet();
        String status = user.compare(un,pw);

        System.out.println(status); //only used to check if desired output is returned.

    }
}
```

and here is my implementation of the model class

```
public class UserInitializer {

public static List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

public void initializeSet() {

    users.add(new User("User1", "abcd"));
    users.add(new User("User2", "wxzy"));
    users.add(new User("User3", "1234"));

}

public String compare(String u, String p) {

    Iterator<User> iterate = users.iterator();
    int stop = 0;
    String username = null;

    while (iterate.hasNext() && (stop == 0)) {

        User user = iterate.next();

        if (user.getUsername().equals(u)) {
            if (user.getPassword().equals(p)) {
                username = u;
                stop = 1;
            }
        } 
        else {
            username = "Invalid"; //username not found
        }
    }

    return username;
}}
```

my User class

```
class User {

private String username, password;

public User(String u, String p) {
    this.username = u;
    this.password = p;
}

public void setUsername(String u) {
    this.username = u;
}

public void setPassword(String p) {
    this.password = p;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return username;
}}
```

I've tried working on this using only a plain Java project and it worked perfectly fine but when I implemented it in my servlet, compare() method only returns "Invalid".

I think there's something wrong with my initializeSet method. Can someone confirm this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `request.getParameter("username");`

Comment: Make sure that capitalization is the same. Or use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`.

Comment: @Jens username is textfield from my jsp. It takes the user's input.

Comment: @pgpdmzn But you says `only returns "Invalid".` do you must test it with some input

Comment: The best way to find out what is happening, is using a debugger

Comment: @Jens yes, I do test it with my jsp. But for some reason, even if my input matches the items in my ArrayList, it still returns "Invalid"

Comment: So you tested it with Input `User1`?

Comment: Can you give us the code of class `User`?

Comment: At the very least print `un` where you print that `status` and give us what is printed ther.

Comment: @pgpdmzn I think your `compare` method is a bit overcomplicated. Don't reinvent the wheel. `users.stream()
    .filter(user -> user.getUsername().equals(u))
    .filter(user -> user.getPassword().equals(p))
    .map(User::getUsername)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse("Invalid");`. By the way, when username is found, but password is invalid you return null, I am not sure whether it is expected.

Comment: @Jens yes I have tested it with User1. Also, I added the code for my user class.

Comment: @RealSkeptic it only prints whatever is the user's input from the textfield in my jsp

Comment: @pgpdmzn `getPassowrod()` returns `username`?

Comment: @Jens THANK YOU SO MUCH TT__TT silly me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `User` class is wrong.

```
public String getPassword() {
    return username;
}
```

This method should return the password, not the user name.

What happens is that when it sees the *correct* username, it compares the password with what is returned from `getPassword()`. But that is not the password, so it moves on to the next user.

The next user is not correct, so it sets the user name to "Invalid".

First thing is to correct that method. Also, if you matched the correct user, *always* stop the loop, whether or not the password is correct. There is no point in continuing to match the user to the rest of the list.